# Android Aviary shows many errors in import

Tags: android, gradle, android-styles, aviary

Aviary SDK not working in Android studio 1.0, see the attachment.
Anyone help?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's related to a similar issue I faced on Aviary SDK with Android Studio 1.0.

Can you check if this gradle configuration resolves your problem ?

```
compile('com.aviary.android.feather.sdk:aviary-sdk:3.4.3.351') {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.commons', module: 'commons-io'
    exclude group: 'commons-io', module: 'commons-io'
    exclude group: 'com.aviary.android.feather.sdk', module: 'common-library'
}

compile('com.aviary.android.feather.sdk:common-library:3.1.2') {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.commons', module: 'commons-io'
    exclude group: 'commons-io', module: 'commons-io'
}

compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'
```

Comment: Actually this is a real answer with a real solution. I'm in discussion with Aviary for the same.